# Copying from one table to other, how to enforce foreign key check on the whole data set but not on separate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL. Let's assume I have a table `hierarchy` with two columns: `id`, `parent_id`.

The `parent_id` refers to `id` of other row of the same table, so I have the foreign key there.

The `hierarchy` table contains some data, but they are not relevant now.

I also have a second table called `new_hierarchy_entries` that has the same columns, but there are no foreign key restrictions set.

`new_hierarchy_entries` contains:

```
id    parent_id
2     1
1     null
```

Now I want to copy all the rows from `new_hierarchy_entries` into `hierarchy`. When I run naively:

```
INSERT INTO hierarchy SELECT * FROM new_hierarchy_entries
```

I get error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (my_db.`hierarchy`, CONSTRAINT hierarchy_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES `hierarchy` (id))

Of course, if the rows are inserted one by one, the first row (id=2, parent=1) cannot be inserted, because there is no row with id=1 in table `hierarchy`.

On the other hand, if all rows were added at once, then the constraints would be satisfied. So how can I copy the rows in such a way that I'm sure that constraints are satisfied after the copying, but they may not be satisfied while copying?

Sorting rows of `new_hierarchy_entries` by `id` will not help. I cannot assume that `parent_id < id` in the same row.

Sorting rows of `new_hierarchy_entries` by the hierarchy (using tree terminology, give me leaves first, then their parents etc.) would help, but I'm not sure how to do that in MySQL query.

I played with the idea of temporarily turning the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS off. But then I could insert inconsistent data and I wouldn't find out. Turning FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS on doesn't make the database check consistency of all the data. It would take too much resources anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky. I don't know any way to make MySQL re-check foreign key references after enabling FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS.

You could check yourself for orphan rows, and if there are any, roll back.

```
BEGIN;

SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT INTO hierarchy SELECT * FROM new_hierarchy_entries;
SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hierarchy AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN hierarchy AS p ON p.id=c.parent_id
WHERE p.id IS NULL;
-- if count == 0 then...
COMMIT;

-- otherwise ROLLBACK and investigate the bad data
```

One other possibility is to use INSERT with the IGNORE option, which will skip failed rows. Then repeat the same statement in a loop, as long as you see "rows affected" more than 0.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO hierarchy SELECT * FROM new_hierarchy_entries;
INSERT IGNORE INTO hierarchy SELECT * FROM new_hierarchy_entries;
INSERT IGNORE INTO hierarchy SELECT * FROM new_hierarchy_entries;
...
```